# Including styles in React application

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have the javascript code written to be implemented on other sites. It's like small modal window that is opened for user purposes. While developing it i were using semantic ui stylesheets. But now I understood that if user want to add this window to his site, he should also add the styles, to make it look like it was developed and designed. But the styles is global, I mean semantic styles. And there two possible situation. User adds semantic styles and the site is broken, or user didn't use semantic styles and then my window is broken. What is the best way for me to solve this problem. How can I attach semantic styles only to my window?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `iframe` and attach style sheet inside it, It will only effect the `Components/Contents` inside the `Iframe` -

Check the details in this link - ***[iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)***

Comment: in this case i should host my own site?